# Formatting html Django-cms

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I create a app, where I can put html code like this

```
<h2>where we are?</h2> 
<h4>Main Offices</h4>
```

My problem is when I show in my view I see the text with the html tags,

I try this `{{ item|striptags }}` but this remove the html tag from the page, even when I inspect the element it's look like string 
`"where we are? Main Offices"`

What is the way in django-cms to don't see the html tag in the view, but when I inspect the element the tags is there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django [automatically escapes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping) the output of every variable tag, to protect you from [Cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You can disable auto-escaping by using the `safe` template filter: `{{ item|safe }}`.